# How to configure MOCP mapping and Expression with metahuman and Live Link

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine5

as my title says I am having trouble mapping face data from the Live Link app to a metahuman.

**Here is what I have done so far:**

- Created a UE5 project (Film/Video & Live Event)
- Imported a metahuman (custom-made) into the project
- Added required plugins to project (Live Link, ArKit, Apple-etc)
- Connected Live Link mobile application to local network
- Set the metahuman's animation controller to the Live Link feed
- Calibrated the Live Link data within the Live Link application

**The problem I am having:**

- Parts of the face are not responding at all (ex. metahuman's right eyebrow does not respond to me lifting my left eyebrow).
- The left corner of the mouth seems to be stuck (ex. when I try to open my mouth, all points respond except for the single point stays where it is).
- The mapping/naming of facial components seems to be mirrored/off/labeled wrong (ex. if I was to wink my right eye this would result in my right eye closing and my right cheek pressing upward. On the metahuman, the left eye would blink and the right cheek would raise.)

These issues are very frustrating as I can not seem to get past this basic calibration. I see online people using these same tools and getting results with the metahuman's facial movements that are really clean. Is there something I am missing? I know that after the metahuman has been calibrated, I will create sequences, am I supposed to be modifying these value there? I am not sure... I have commented on every video I can find and I have posted this question in the Unreal Discord (here) with basically no help.
Note: I don't need a full solution, I just need to be pointed in the right direction! Please let me know if there is anything I am missing in my setup or calibration workflow.

thanks for reading.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that I was doing everything right. After upgrading from 5.0.3 to 5.1 the issue stopped completely.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem with a customer project, and the issue was it wasn't using the correct animation blueprint.  Once we switched it to the correct animation blueprint for LiveLink the issue was immediately resolved.  I remember that exact same facial expression - sorry as I know this was a frustrating one for the customer as well.

Comment: Thank you for responding. So I am accessing the wrong animation blueprint? Would you have any information on how to access the correct BP?

Comment: The MetaHuman's have multiple animation blueprints, on the body and on the face.  The issue we ran into was the Face animation blueprint was using a non-live link version and so the mappings were wrong causing the issue your showing there.  This was caused for them because they had a old MetaHuman that they hadn't updated with the new Animation BP that is autogenerated from the MetaHuman creator, when you bring down your character.  So easy step, is to bring in a brand new character and wire it up.  Should use the latest BP automatically.